# Find items common between two Active record items array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I get two resulting arrays (ActiveRecord items) like:

```
 users =  [1, 3]

 users2 =  [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to combine and find the intersection for the result , ie I want [1, 3] active record items.
How do I accomplish this?

Comment: How are you obtaining these results in the first place? Do you need both results independent of the intersection?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a bitwise operator `&`:

```rb
common_elements = users & users2
```

**EDIT**: thanks @engineersmnky for keeping me honest, it's not actually a bitwise operator but a method on [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-26).

Comment: Not a bitwise operator in this context. [`Array#&`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-26) is a method call for Set Intersection but terminology aside your answer is not incorrect.